# Why using a DateTimeProvider interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, interface

I have seen this interface many times already:

```cs
    public interface IDateTimeProvider
    {
        DateTime Now { get; }
        DateTime UtcNow { get; }
        DateTimeOffset OffsetNow { get; }
        DateTimeOffset OffsetUtcNow { get; }
    }
```

I simply don't understand why using this more verbose approach rather than simply using the static properties of the `DateTime` `DateTimeOffset`.
Under what circumstances using the date provider can be better than using the static properties directly?

```cs
public SomeService(IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
{
  this._dateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
}


public void SomeMethod()
 {
      var date = _dateTimeProvider.UtcNow;
      // var date = DateTime.UtcNow; // why not this
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Try to write a unit test for this code and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

In a word, testability.  Being able to "hard code" certain times in the past, or future, outside business hours, etc, to exercise different code paths in your app's unit tests.